# Dois spinners que não podem ter o mesmo valor selecionado

Tags: java, android

Ola, eu tenho um código que tem dois spinners e que caso selecionamos uma opção num spinner no outro essa opção deixa de existir , o que eu fiz foi o seguinte : Sempre que clica no spinner ele faz clear e adiciona todos e depois remove o que esta selecionado no outro de modo a não se poder seleccionar o mesmo nos dois! Mas quando seleciono alguma coisa num , ele entra num loop infinito , como se estivesse sempre a efetuar o método OnItemSelected alguém sabe porque ? Aqui esta o código:

```
   disciplinasFirst.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                disciplinasFirst.add("Física e Química A");
                disciplinasFirst.add("Geometria Descritiva A");
                disciplinasFirst.add("Química");



                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDitsciplinasFirst = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChoseDisciplinas2.this, R.layout.spinner_item_beggin, disciplinasFirst);

                adapterDitsciplinasFirst.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                SpinnerFirst.setAdapter(
                        new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                adapterDitsciplinasFirst,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
                                this));


                disciplinasSecond.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                disciplinasSecond.add("Física e Química A");
                disciplinasSecond.add("Geometria Descritiva A");
                disciplinasSecond.add("Química");



                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDisciplinasSecond = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChoseDisciplinas2.this, R.layout.spinner_item_beggin, disciplinasSecond);

                adapterDisciplinasSecond.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                SpinnerSecond.setAdapter(
                        new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                adapterDisciplinasSecond,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
                                this));

                SpinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (SpinnerFirst.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                            disciplinasSecond.clear();
                            disciplinasSecond.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                            disciplinasSecond.add("Física e Química A");
                            disciplinasSecond.add("Geometria Descritiva A");
                            disciplinasSecond.add("Química");
                            disciplinasSecond.remove(SpinnerFirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDisciplinasSecond = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChoseDisciplinas2.this, R.layout.spinner_item_beggin, disciplinasSecond);
                            SpinnerSecond.setAdapter(adapterDisciplinasSecond);
                            Log.d(Tag,"fui selecionado2");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }

                });
                SpinnerFirst.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if(SpinnerSecond.getSelectedItem()!=null){
                            disciplinasFirst.clear();
                            disciplinasFirst.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                            disciplinasFirst.add("Física e Química A");
                            disciplinasFirst.add("Geometria Descritiva A");
                            disciplinasFirst.add("Química");
                            disciplinasFirst.remove(SpinnerSecond.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDitsciplinasFirst = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChoseDisciplinas2.this, R.layout.spinner_item_beggin, disciplinasFirst);
                            SpinnerFirst.setAdapter(adapterDitsciplinasFirst);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }

                });

            }
```

Disciplinas First e Disciplinas Second são o conteúdo dos Spinners nest caso o Spinner First e Spinner Second respetivamente.

Muito obrigado e uma boa noite ou boa tarde para os brasileiros!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que o seu algoritmo deveria ser: se eu selecionar algo no primeiro Spinner, altera o conteudo do segundo; e vice-versa. Do jeito que fez, sempre que fizer uma escolha no primeiro, o conteúdo dele será alterado o que equivale a fazer uma nova seleção ativando o onItemSelected recursivamente.

Mas esse algoritmo também pode causar um problema semelhante: quando seleciona um valor, o onItemSelected vai alterar o outro spinner, cujo onItemSelected vai alterar o primeiro, que por sua vez ira novamente alterar o segundo, ... Não tenho android, portanto não testei.

Solução simples: use um `boolean` como 'guarda' para evitar que o onItemSelected faça alguma alteração se já tiver um outro rodando.

Esquema:

```
private boolean selecionando = false;

SpinnerFirst.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!selecionando) {
            selecionando = true;
            try {
                if (SpinnerFirst.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    disciplinasSecond.clear();
                    disciplinasSecond.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                    ...
                    disciplinasSecond.remove(SpinnerFirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ...
                }
            } finally {
                selecionando = false;
            }
        }
    }
});

SpinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!selecionando) {
            selecionando = true;
            try {
                if (SpinnerSecond.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    disciplinasFirst.clear();
                    disciplinasFirst.add("Biologia e Geologia");
                    ...
                    disciplinasFirst.remove(SpinnerSecond.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ...
                }
            } finally {
                selecionando = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

O try-finally é para garantir, mesmo no caso de uma Exception, que `selecionando` seja resetada. Syncronização nào deve ser problema pois esses métodos sempre são chamados da mesma Thread.

**Obs:**

esse esquema é muito *instável* e complicado, talvez funcione melhor se deixar todas as opções nos spinner e, caso o usuário escolher a mesma opçõa, simplesmente desabilitar o botão que aceita a escolha.